# How to read these post parameters in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the below post request where i'm trying to get the teams id value.

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "_method"=>"put",
 "authenticity_token"=>"knq4dG1U/5NJxMD6KYxfOpKd3CuOBHRlp6xCwdpwCnQ=",
 "match"=>{"name"=>"latest match",
 "date(1i)"=>"2013",
 "date(2i)"=>"5",
 "date(3i)"=>"19",
 "teams_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"name"=>"Navi",
 "id"=>"1"},
 "1369038961631"=>{"name"=>"A team",
 "id"=>"2"}}},
 "commit"=>"Update Match",
 "match_id"=>"2"}
```

If i do this then i can extract the record for one of the values

```
params.first["match"]["teams_attributes"]["0"]["id"]
```

But i'll be dealing with an array of 'teams_attributes' so i'm doing this loop but it's returning a nil value.

```
  teams = params.first["match"]["teams_attributes"]   <---gets the teams_attributes array.

  teams.each do |tea|

    teamid = tea.first["id"]
    puts teamid

  end
```

Comment: Why are you doing `.first`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your one has a nested `Hash`,inside `teams`. Look below:

```
teams.each {|h| p h}
#=>["0", {"name"=>"Navi", "id"=>"1"}]
#=>["1369038961631", {"name"=>"A team", "id"=>"2"}]
```

Do as below:

```
teams.each_value.map{|v| v['id']} #=> ["1", "2"]
```

Comment: Thanks, is this the only way to do it in rails when using custom routes?  I would like to do this 'Team.find(params[:team_id]' but that doesn't work. Not sure why when Teams is a nested attribute of Match.

Comment: I know Ruby only. No idea about `ROR`. :(

Answer (score 2):

`params.first` will definitely not work, because you are dealing with a Hash and not with an Array as it seems. Therefore `params.first` will return `["utf8", "✓"]`.

Secondly, using `each` on a Hash will assign an Array to `tea`, containing a key and a value from the Hash. Consider:

```
teams = params['match']['teams_attributes']
teams.each do |tea|
  p tea
end

# ["0", {"name"=>"Navi", "id"=>"1"}]
# ["1369038961631", {"name"=>"A team", "id"=>"2"}]
```

so when you use `tea.first` you will get the key, not the value. In your example `tea.first` would yield `"0"` and `"1369038961631"` respectively. You can write a block with two parameters to only get the value, i.e.

```
teams.each do |key,team|
  # ...
end
```

but since you don't use the `key`, you might as well use the anonymous block parameter `_`, which will discard the key:

```
teams.each do |_,team|
  # ...
end
```

Try it with this code instead:

```
teams = params['match']['teams_attributes']

teams.each do |_,team|
  team_id = team['id']
  puts team_id
end

# 1
# 2
```

If you want an array of team ids, you can use `map`:

```
teams = params['match']['teams_attributes']

team_ids = teams.map do |_,team|
  team['id']
end

p team_ids
# ["1", "2"]
```

Comment: seems you and me on the same page.:)

Comment: Yeah, didn't see your answer until i had submitted mine ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use following code, In this `id_array` will give you id of all the teams.

```
id_array = []
teams = params["match"]["teams_attributes"]
teams.keys.each do |key|
 id_array << teams[key]["id"]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You are cooking it wrong if you think too much on hacking a team's id.

The reason there is `team_attributes` is you have such class macro in Match model

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :teams
```

So, in your controller

```
@match = Match.build(params[:match])
```

Then you can use Match model's instance variable to access teams value

```
@teams = @match.teams
@team1 = @teams.first
teams1_id = @team1.id # Though I really don't think you need to do that!
```